# Angular material chip list with autocomplete show on add button click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular material chip list with autocomplete but in the example it shows drop-down when you place cursor near the last added chip but I want to show an add button near to the lastly added chip and show autocomplete only after user has clicked on plus icon

Like this - https://angular-zqijrv.stackblitz.io
but here, when I remove all chips, there is a weird border/outline which I cant remove and input box should be shown only when add is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is

you can try to show chips in read only text box and when

```
 <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [readonly]="readonl"   -- // add a readonly attribute
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
```

as user select the chip

```
// html file event
    (optionSelected)="selectChip()" this event is fired when you select something from the dropdown.

  // ts file
    selectChip(){
    // your code 
  this.readonl = true;
    }
```

// user is not able to type anything

and from your add button you can make this readonl flag to false and set focus in input box so that user can type and see dropdown.

---

2nd approach
have a 2 variable one with master data variable and other is copy of master data in autocomplete data variable.

```
 // ts file 
    masterData = [x,y,z]
    autoComplete = [...this.master]

// html file event
    (optionSelected)="selectChip()" this event is fired when you select something from the dropdown.

  // ts file
    selectChip(){
    // your code 
    this.autocomplete.length = 0; // make autocomplete length to 0 items and add a logic to move focus to some other element.
    }

    // when u click on add button
    addButton() {
    autoComplete = [...this.master]
    }
    // now the dropdown have items and will appear again.
```

---

Comment: Can you refer link I added?